# adding same class to dynamic created elements with javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

Hello!

So for each category in an online shop i have a page with every subcategory included and a table with products.
I have [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wOFu.png) with sorting buttons on top for each subcategory of products. What I want is to put the same color as the buttons to each row(product) in the table.
So where the product is from the Display subcategory the color should be green and so on.

This needs to be done dynamically because I have more pages like that, created from the database.
[Another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvJHH.png)

To add the subcategory colors I'm using a simple

```
$class++
```

in the while loop. with css classes created like

```
.col1{
   color: #3e8f3e;
}
.col2{
   color: #e38d13;
}
.col3{
   color: #b92c28;
}
.col4{
   color: #DC4C46;
}
.col5{
   color: #672E3B;
}
.col6{
   color: #F3D6E4;
}
.col7{
   color: #C48F65;
}
.col8{
   color: #223A5E;
}
.col9{
   color: #898E8C;
}
.col10{
   color: #005960;
}
.col11{
   color: #9C9A40;
}
.col12{
   color: #4F84C4;
}
```

I used the subcatergory name as the id of the button.
Code for button:

```
<li>
    <a type="button" class="btn-filter" id="'.$row['subcat_pro'].'" href="#go" title="'.$row['subcat_pro'].'" data-target="'.$row['subcat_pro'].'">'.$row['subcat_pro'].'</a><hr class="btn'.$class++.'">
</li>';
```

Code for the `<span>` where the color should be:

```
<span id="sub'.$row['subcat_pro'] .'" class="pull-right">('. $row['subcat_pro'] .') (SKU: '. $row['sku'] .')</span>
```

I really have no idea of what can be done.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you tell me what are you getting and what do you need ??

Comment: What I want is to put the same color as the buttons to each row(product) in the table. So where the product is from the Display subcategory the color should be green and so on.

Comment: it's there man... I'm bad at explaining ... sorry

Comment: no.its ok can you just name the classes with the sub categoryname ??

Comment: I can... but how do i add color to them? Like `class=Display` and in css `.Display { color:green }`... remeber i have 32 subcatergories..

Comment: ok are you just for looping now to create css classes ??

Comment: I am `while` looping and adding a `$class++` for each subcategory in the upper part of the table(in the buttons)

Comment: `while($row = $db->db_fetch_array($subcat)) {

      $tmptxt .= '          <li>
                                <a type="button" class="btn-filter" id="'.$row['subcat_pro'].'" href="#go" title="'.$row['subcat_pro'].'" data-target="'.$row['subcat_pro'].'">'.$row['subcat_pro'].'</a><hr class="btn'.$class++.'">
                            </li>';
       }` the code for the buttons

Comment: ok then you can do the same while loop to create the classes with the subcategory name.just do that and just add any prefix like cls to not make a conflict.

Comment: like 
$css = "<style>";
while($row = $db->db_fetch_array($subcat)) {
$css .= ".cls".$row['subcat_pro']."."{ color :".$random_colour_code."}";
}
$css .= "</style>";
echo $css;

Comment: OK... I'll try and see what I can do. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

honestly, i would put that color IN your "categories" or "subcategories" table, like, i would create a colunm called "color" and then when you are creating your table you could do something like this:

```
<?php 
    $categories = $db ... // get your categories here using a query

    foreach($categories as $category) {
          <span name="category_{$category['id']}" style="color:{$category['color']}" ><span>
    }
?>
```

But, if you don't like styles in-line on your HTML, like i don't, you will have to define all those colors as classes on your CSS file, then, you would build that html using those classes.

Let me know if you want a example for the second option (which is pretty hard work).

Comment: yeah thought 'bout putting a column with colors... the problem is... that the data is from a magento based shop... if a new category/subcategory is createad i would have to manually add the color... a friend of mine suggested javascript... but I'm really new to javascript

Comment: Hmm, but, anyway, you will have to add the colors somewhere ... even using javascript or in the database ... i can make an example using javascript tho.

Comment: I think i'll make a new table, to connect the subcategories to colors... i guess it's the easiest way. and i really don't mind in-line css because it's an local app

Comment: Well, i think that's it, there is no many ways to do this, those colors need to be defined somewhere and if it's in database, javascript or css doesn't really matter, you'll have a manual job still to do everytime a category is added.

Comment: The perfect scenario would be a CRUD of categories having a "Color" field, i mean, an administration part where you can create a new category and fill a "select color" field and then you save it in the database ... but, as you said, it's coming from magento, so your options here would be asking the guys to change the form of catogories ( or do yourself idk if you know magento) or create manually those relations. (sorry for bad english).